# How to deal with json with single quote in datatable in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe, datatable, jsonlite

I have a datatable with JSON. And I use `jsonlite` to deal with it.

```
library(data.table)
library(jsonlite)
a <- data.table(keyword = list("{'id': 2316, 'name': 'women's sexual identity'}"))
```

In order to use `fromJSON`, I need to convert `'` to `"`.

```
a[, keywords2 := gsub("'", "\"", keyword)]
a[, fromJSON(keywords2, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)]
```

But since there are `'` in the `name`, like `'women's sexual identity'`. After transformation, the record becomes this `{"id": 2316, "name": "women"s sexual identity"}`. It would generate error:

```
> a[, rbindlist(lapply(keywords2, fromJSON), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)]
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
           {"id": 2316, "name": "women"s sexual identity"}
                     (right here) ------^
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try with

```
a[, keywords2 := gsub("'(?![a-z])|(?<=\\{|\\s)'", '"', keyword, perl = TRUE)]

cat(a$keywords2, '\n')
#{"id": 2316, "name": "women's sexual identity"} 


a[, prettify(toJSON(keywords2))]
#[
# "{\"id\": 2316, \"name\": \"women's sexual identity\"}"
#]
```

Comment: but the  'women's sexual identity' is still single quote.

Comment: @Harold Isn't that you wanted.  I thought you want only double quotes for the 'id' and 'name'

Comment: Sorry. But it seems that fromJson can only recognize characters quoted by a double quote.

Comment: is there any wildcard in R. Maybe`gsub( ' * ' * ', " * ' * ", keywords)`?

Comment: @Harold Can you please check whether the update is okay